# Setting a configuration that lives as a parent of the compile configuration in Gradle

Tags: plugins, gradle

I added a custom configuration to my plugin

```
Configuration customCompile = project.configurations.create("customCompile")
        .setVisible(false).setTransitive(true)
```

I want to do something like

```
configuration.compile.addExtendsFrom(customCompile)
```

So that in my plugin, I can isolate certain dependencies to add to the classpath of something I'm running (with `project.configurations.customCompile).  I want them to remain on the regular compile path as well.

What I did was this :

```
Configuration compile = project.configurations.getByName('compile')
Set updated = WrapUtil.asSet(compile.getExtendsFrom()) // returns a immutable set
updated.add(customCompile)
compile.setExtendsFrom(updated)
```

It works, but it feels a little convoluted, `extendsFrom` seems to have the opposite meaning of inheritance that I'm used to with java classes.  Is there a better way to be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.extendsFrom(b)` *is* analogue to "a inherits from b", and you can simply do `configurations.compile.extendsFrom(customCompile)`. (Not `addExtendsFrom` or `getExtendsFrom`.)

Comment: The reason I think it feels like the opposite of inheritance is because of how I think "instanceof" would work.  If a.extendsfrom(b), I would expect project.configurations.a to be a list of the subclass "a", and project.configurations.b to include b and a. Anyway, I guess that's a subjective interpretation. This works for me.

Comment: Your interpretation is the opposite of inheritance. :-) extendsFrom is really analogue to (multiple) inheritance.

Comment: What I meant is in the context of what a list of type 'B' could reference (type A and B) vs a list of type 'A' (type A), but this seems to be have the meaning that all B type dependencies are members of B (not instances of B) which make sense.